# how to handle transaction management in JPA between two war files (two diff DB's)

Tags: distributed-transactions

I have two PostgreSQL databases. I'll send request to one database to do some DML operations , based on success response I'll send request to second database to do some DML operations. If second operation is failed, how can I roolback first DB DML operations.

Hope you all understood my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Standard rollback does not apply since you need the result from statement 1 and use it for 2nd statement. You need to do this in your app outside sql.

For the 'artificial rollback', you need to cache the original values for the row(s) effected by the operation

The flow will work on the following lines:

```
select * from table where the_Where; //statement 1

update db1.table set updates where the_Where;

--if success--
update db2.table set updates where another_Where;

--if failure--
update table set (data from statement 1) where the_Where;
```